# How to see notifications timing in KDE 4.1x?

Tags: linux, notifications, kde-4

KDE 4.1x doesn’t show time against the notification it puts in front of the user. E.g.:- copy/move files task has completed, a torrent has completed, battery low-level notifications, etc…,  the only relevant part you see is the text.

I’m interested in knowing the time when the notification occurred: like when my torrent finished, or files copy completed, etc…

Note:- I’m aware of the sound alert functionality in notifications but that’s not practically useful if the user isn’t around the system.

- **OS:** Slackware 14.1, Linux Mint 17 Qiana
- **KDE version:** 4.10, 4.13.3
- **Kernel:** 3.10, 3.13